# Share a table on multiple database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a advice if my idea is good or wrong.

I use opencart and I want to create 2 store. Let's say I have this:

1. site1 use `db1`
2. site2 use `db2`

What I want is for table from `db1` like `address,customer,orders` also to be use it on `db2` by site 2.

Is any way to share a table from `db1` to `db2`? and also let site2 to modify,edit,select from this table?!

I know I can use `multistore` but I don`t want to use this option(many reason). I know also I can modify files from site2 to use db1.address but I believe on My SQL should already have something for what I ask.

I know I can create something like this `CREATE VIEW db2.address AS SELECT * FROM db1.address` but I understand this is not the best idea because have some limitation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no use in creating same tables in different schemas, because updates and deletes would be an overhead then.

Either you can go with creating a schema named **GLOBAL**
 which will the physical existence of the table and the rest schema will use its **view**

OR

You can create a **VIEW** of the table in other schemas.

Comment: And if i create view i will not have any problem?! I mean opencart will read,edit and delet from that table?!